# issues with windows msi installer win 7 pro

Tags: windows-7-x64, windows-installer

I tried to install this program that open by windows msi installer and there was  problem with a message "Installation incomplete" follow with error message below " The installer was interrupted before FaxFinder Client software could be installed, you need to restart the installer to try again".

This is software for digital fax and we are using the old version, I already been doing this many times already with success installations, if there was a problem, I usually trouble shoot it by restart the windows 7, and log back in with my admin rights.

But this time is different, I have been tried so many times and always showing the error message. On installation progress I saw that all files are installed into a folder, and located on program files (using x64 bit), but when the installation about to finished, I saw Status: Rolling back action, stopping services(I believe it stopped at point print spooler) and ended in result "Installation Incomplete".

I am using windows 7 pro OS and part of admin group in my network. Could somebody help me with this error message please? I appreciate it.

Edit:my questions might be not really clear, ok let me try this again:
when I checked the print spooler from services.msc showing a weird behavior, it stopped, started, and stopped again, I set the start up type to automatic, and I have admin rights on this computer. I also tried to install the program in safe mode, but it won't let me install it. the program itself doesn't have run as admin option.

Comment: You should contact the vendor to get tech support.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your response. I found out from vendor's website, that saying windows KB3072630 preventing installation, to whoever has the same problem like mine, please check this [link](http://www.multitech.com/support/resolution/30613), that works only if you installed faxfinder client older version (ff20). 
Hope this could help!